# regex strip spaces hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I am unable to strip one space before and after a hyphen.  I have tried: -

```
sample.replaceAll("[\\s\\-\\s]","")
```

and permutations to no avail.  I dont want to strip all spaces, neither all the intervening spaces.  I am trying to parse a string based on `" "` but want to eliminate `"-"`.  Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[\s\-\s]` is a character class, and does not matches `space followed by - followed by space`. It matches any of the characters - `space`, and `-`, and replace them with `empty string`.

You can use this: -

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("[ ]-[ ]","-");
```

Or, even `String.replace` would work here. You don't really need a `replaceAll`: -

```
sample = sample.replace(" - ", "-");
```

Comment: I just wanna throw it out there, that `[ ]` is a nice way to make literal spaces more visible in regular expressions, and shows that they have been put there intentionally.

Comment: @m.buettner.. Yeah that's a good point. I rather used `\\s`. In fact I added both. :)

Comment: that is not equivalent. `\\s` matches spaces, tabs, carriage returns and line feeds. But sometimes you really just want to match the space character.

Comment: I don't see why you need `replaceAll` - `replace(" - ", "-")` is better here.

Comment: @A.R.S... Yeah you are right. In fact that should be used. I just copy pasted the code from OP.

Comment: Hi All
Actually I was trying to escape "-" not use it as an range operator and indeed it does not work as I have starting and ending
powder, argentina - raw organic - 2 oz  
rather than
powder argentina raw organic 2 oz
Yes, I added the stripping of "," also
Is there a way to produce the first adduct?

Comment: @cp... You never told that you want to just remove `" - "` completely. You just told that you want to strip the spaces. Also there was no talking about `,` in your question. Please clearly specify what you want. Meanwhile, you can modify the regex I gave to remove `" - "`, by replacing it with `""`

Comment: Thank you
I used your technique and then separate pass for the comma.  Can you explain why this did not work?
savedDesc=savedDesc.replaceAll("[,\\-]*","");

Comment: @cp. Well what do you want it to do first?